# how to avoid repeating similar markup in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

in my xaml file I have two identical DataGrids that are bound to different collections, and have different names, and different Grid.Column attributes. Is there a way to not repeat the markup for these data grids but have something more concise? Like a macro substitution in programming languages?

      `<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding View0}"
                Name="DataGrid0"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                Grid.Column="0"
                views:DataGridProperties.RowEditEndingCommand="{Binding UpdateTaskCommand}">
      ...
      </DataGrid>
      ...
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding View1}"
                Name="DataGrid1"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTask}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                Grid.Column="1"
                views:DataGridProperties.RowEditEndingCommand="{Binding UpdateTaskCommand}">
      ...
      </DataGrid>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Styles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) for identical values, that usually takes care of most properties, and if the properties are not identical there usually is no need to go any further.

Comment: @akonsu: I could but won't. Read the docs i linked to and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do this, and i dont think there is a single right answer for this.
Here's just a few off the top of my head:

A) You could have a datagrid "generator", like a function, and load your datagrid dynamically via code.

B) Uou could load your datagrid dynamically via xaml (load xaml markup).

C) Have a single datagrid defined in your xaml. Then dynamically add additional datagrids to a ContentControl, ItemsControl, a StackPanel, or whatever, with the propeties copied over from the first datagrid.

D) You can create a UserControl which defines your datagrid (i.e. Custom DataGrid control). Then you simply add this datagrid via Xaml or code.